# sed pattern negation with a comma separated line

Tags: sed

I have a text file full of lines looking like:

```
Female,"$0 to $25,000",Arlington Heights,0,60462,ZD111326,9/18/13 0:21,Disk Drive
```

I am trying to change all of the commas `,` to pipes `|`, except for the commas within the quotes.
Trying to use sed (which I am new to)... and it is not working.   Using:

```
sed '/".*"/!s/\,/|/g' textfile.csv
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Revised:  I think the negation pattern is causing the whole line to be skipped.   Is this possible?

Comment: You are correct, sed is working on the whole line so when it finds your regex it matches the line, when you ! negate it drops the whole line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a test case, consider this file:

```
Female,"$0 to $25,000",Arlington Heights,0,60462,ZD111326,9/18/13 0:21,Disk Drive
foo,foo,"x,y,z",foo,"a,b,c",foo,"yes,no"
"x,y,z",foo,"a,b,c",foo,"yes,no",foo
```

Here is a `sed` command to replace non-quoted commas with pipe symbols:

```
$ sed -r ':a; s/^([^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*),/\1|/g; t a' file 
Female|"$0 to $25,000"|Arlington Heights|0|60462|ZD111326|9/18/13 0:21|Disk Drive
foo|foo|"x,y,z"|foo|"a,b,c"|foo|"yes,no"
"x,y,z"|foo|"a,b,c"|foo|"yes,no"|foo
```

#### Explanation

This looks for commas that appear after *pairs* of double quotes and replaces them with pipe symbols.

- `:a`

  This defines a label `a`.
- `s/^([^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*),/\1|/g`

  If 0, 2, 4, or any an even number of quotes precede a comma on the line, then replace that comma with a pipe symbol.

  - `^`

    This matches at the start of the line.
  - (`

    This starts the main grouping (`\1`).
  - `[^"]*`

    This looks for zero or more non-quote characters.
  - `("[^"]*"[^"]*)*`

    The `*` outside the parens means that we are looking for zero or more of the pattern inside the parens.  The pattern inside the parens consists of a quote, any number of non-quotes, a quote and then any number on non-quotes.

    In other words, this grouping only matches *pairs* of quotes.  Because of the `*` outside the parens, it can match any even number of quotes.
  - `)`

    This closes the main grouping
  - `,`

    This requires that the grouping be followed by a comma.
- `t a`

  If the previous `s` command successfully made a substitution, then the `test` command tells `sed` to jump back to label `a` and try again.

  If no substitution was made, then we are done.

Comment: Well done, I never thought about nesting hold spaces, I guess sed is meant for that.. =)

Answer (score 0):

using awk could be eaiser:

```
kent$  cat f
foo,foo,"x,y,z",foo,"a,b,c",foo,"yes,no"
Female,"$0 to $25,000",Arlington Heights,0,60462,ZD111326,9/18/13 0:21,Disk Drive

kent$  awk -F'"' -v OFS='"' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i%2)gsub(",","|",$i)}7' f
foo|foo|"x,y,z"|foo|"a,b,c"|foo|"yes,no"
Female|"$0 to $25,000"|Arlington Heights|0|60462|ZD111326|9/18/13 0:21|Disk Drive
```

Comment: Also, why is the "7" at the end of that for loop?

Comment: @Sam Its used to get the print out.  It could be any number like  `1` or  `8`.  It will then do the default action, `print`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a language with a proper CSV parser. For example:

```
ruby -rcsv -ne 'puts CSV.generate_line(CSV.parse_line($_), :col_sep=>"|")' file
```

```
Female|$0 to $25,000|Arlington Heights|0|60462|ZD111326|9/18/13 0:21|Disk Drive
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I would have used `gnu awks` `FPAT`.  It define how a field looks like `FS` that tells what the separator is. Then you can just set the output separator to `|`

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=\| FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" file
Female|"$0 to $25,000"|Arlington Heights|0|60462|ZD111326|9/18/13 0:21|Disk Drive
```

---

If your `awk` does not support  `FPAT`, this can be used:

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {c+=gsub(/\"/,"&",$i);printf "%s"(c%2?FS:"|"),$i}print $NF}' file
Female|"$0 to $25,000"|Arlington Heights|0|60462|ZD111326|9/18/13 0:21|Disk Drive
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/"\(.*\),\(.*\)"/"\1##HOLD##\2"/g;s/,/|/g;s/##HOLD##/,/g'
```

This will match the text in quotes and put a placeholder for the commas, then switch all the other commas to pipes and put the placeholder back to commas. You can change the ##HOLD## text to whatever you want.